# slow ftp upload

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, xen, citrix

3 weeks ago we change our server infrastructure and migrate all servers to virtual servers.After that i realize something interesting.When anybody try to upload something via ftp or sftp upload rate is constant 80kb/s.We used different ftp clients and computers for upload,resualt is same.First of all i check download speed of servers.If i download anything to servers via Wget,speed is between 5mb/s and 10mb/s for each server.After that i try to upload somefiles via web-based script and i uploaded them very fast.So ı belive problem is not about our connection speed.
We use Ubuntu server 32bit as servers and Openfiler as SAN/NAS and backup unit.I open ftp accounts for both of them and still both different operation system upload limit via ftp/sftp is 80kb/s.Then i realize that both of them use proftpd so i changed their configuration files to increase upload limit but can't do it.I removed proftp from all Ubuntu servers and install pure-ftp and vsftp.Nothing is changed.
This problem started after we migrate to virtual servers.Before the migration upload speed for both ftp/sftp around 1 mb/s
I can't find a solution.Thanks for your help
Ps:We use Citrix XenServer and have 5 Xenserver 20 virtual servers 2 openfiler.Same for all

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the same problem but when we cloned two of our already virtualised XenApp servers from ESX Server to XenServer, we encountered network performance problems. Our resolution was the one about DisableTaskOffload mentioned in this thread:

http://forums.citrix.com/thread.jspa?threadID=248194&tstart=0

I can't remember what the issue exactly was (read the thread :-)) but it certainly removed general network related performance issues from our XenApp servers on XenCenter.

Rather ironic I think as Citrix sell XenServer as been a better virtualisation platform for XenApp because it's optimised for their product.

Cheers, Rob.